# Issue Creating Class with Boolean

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue creating this class and it's stating that the Set parameters are invalid and error on the below code. I've triple checked this and can't seem to find the issue! Any idea why this error is occurring?

**CODE:**

```
Option Explicit

Private pIsChargeable As Boolean

Public Property Set IsChargeable(value As Boolean)
   pIsChargeable = value
End Property
Public Property Get IsChargeable() As Boolean
   IsChargeable = pIsChargeable
End Property
```

**ERROR:**

> Compile Error:
>
> Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray, or an invalid Set final parameter

Comment: `Property Set` is for `Object` type variables. You need `Property Let`.

Comment: @BigBen This appears to have solved my problem, but arises another question... I used two other variables within this class of type `String`, why would `Property Set` work with strings but not `Boolean`?

Comment: It might be helpful to read Chip Pearson's [explanation](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx) of classes, as well as `Property Set` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/property-set-statement). `Property Set` won't work with `String` variables. See the `Property Let` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/property-let-statement) for an example with `String`s as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Property Set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/property-set-statement) is for `Object` type variables. You're looking for [`Property Let`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/property-let-statement).

It might be helpful to read Chip Pearson's [explanation](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx) of classes as well.